# Use if / case statement in ORDER BY in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, case

I have a stored procedure that fetches data and currently orders it as follows:

```
ORDER BY    dateEsc desc, prio desc, EID desc
```

Is there a way that I can say IF prio = "Urgent" THEN put such a record on the very top of my results and only for the remaining records apply the above order ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following will work, because when `prio = 'Urgent'` then the new condition will generate 0 else 1 and sort by this value first; and later sort by other conditions...

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN prio = "Urgent" THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    dateEsc desc, prio desc, EID desc
```

Comment: You beat me too it :(. That was my exact solution.